Rank of sheaf of differentials greater than dimension of fiber
I would like to prove the following statement (I'm not sure if this is even true):
Let $f\colon X\to Y$ a morphism locally of finite type. For all $x \in X$ we have
$$
\dim_{k(x)}(\Omega_{X/Y,x} \otimes_{\mathcal O_{X,x}} k(x)) \geq \dim(\mathcal O_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal O_{Y,f(x)}} k(f(x)))
$$
My attempt (The basic idea comes from Hartshorne 10.1):
Let $x \in X$ and write $y = f(x)$. We may look at the fiber
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_y @>f'>> k(y) \\
@VjVV @VVV \\
X @>f>> Y
\end{CD}
$$
and we denote the lift $x \in X_y$ also by $x$.
Then we get an isomorphism $j^*(\Omega_{X/Y}) \cong \Omega_{X_y/k(y)}$ by base change and therefore $\Omega_{X/Y,x} \otimes_{\mathcal O_{X,x}} k(x) \cong \Omega_{X_y/k(y),x} \otimes_{\mathcal O_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal O_{Y,y}} k(y)} k(x)$.
Let $X' \subseteq X_y$ be an irreducible component containing $x$ and equip it with the reduced induced structure and look at the closed immersion $i \colon X' \to X$. We get a surjective morphism $i^*(\Omega_{X_y/k(y)}) \twoheadrightarrow \Omega_{X'/k(y)}$ by the second fundamental sequence and therefore a surjective morphism $\Omega_{X_y/k(y),x} \otimes_{\mathcal O_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal O_{Y,y}} k(y)} k(x) \twoheadrightarrow \Omega_{X'/k(y),x} \otimes_{\mathcal O_{X',x}} k(x)$.
Now let $\eta \in X'$ be the generic point, $U = \operatorname{Spec}(A) \subseteq X_y$ an open affine neighborhood of $x$ with $A$ noetherian (as $f'$ is also locally noetherian). Since $X'$ is an irreducible component containing $x$ there exists a minimal prime $p \subseteq A$ with $p \subseteq x$ (here $x$ is also the corresponding prime in $A$) such that $i|_{i^{-1}(U)}$ is induced by the projection $A \to A/p$.
By various statements from Matsumuras Commutative Algebra (marked with "*") we have
$$
\dim_{\mathcal O_{X,\eta}}(\Omega_{X'/k(y),\eta}) = \dim_{\mathcal O_{X,\eta}}(\Omega_{\mathcal O_{X,\eta}/k(y)}) \overset{*}{\geq} \operatorname{trdeg}(\mathcal O_{X,\eta}/k(y)) = \operatorname{trdeg}(\mathcal O_{U,\eta}/k(y)) = \operatorname{trdeg}(\operatorname{Frac}(A/p)/k(y))
$$
$$
\overset{*}{=} \dim(A/p) = \dim(A/p) + \operatorname{ht}(p) \overset{*}{=} \dim(A) \geq \dim(A_x) = \dim(\mathcal O_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal O_{Y,y}} k(y))
$$
But then we also have
$$
\dim_{k(x)}(\Omega_{X'/k(y),x} \otimes_{\mathcal O_{X,x}} k(x)) \geq \dim(\mathcal O_{X,x} \otimes_{\mathcal O_{Y,y}} k(y))
$$
which shows the claim.
Is my argument correct? Have I used something incorrectly which I'm not aware of?

I realized the error I am making in reading your question. So I have deleted my comments. Apologies.
